# Windows Explorer: self implemented Overlay Icons do not work

Tags: c++, windows, icons, overlay, explorer

I'm trying to simply display some overlay icons in the Windows Explorer.
Since I'm relatively new to programming for Windows (I just have some experience in Mac programming), I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) article to start.

So this is my code:

**Icon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "resource.h"
#include "ExplorerSync_i.h"

using namespace ATL;

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CIcon :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CIcon, &CLSID_Icon>,
    public IShellIconOverlayIdentifier,
    public IDispatchImpl<IIcon, &IID_IIcon, &LIBID_ExplorerSyncLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
    CIcon();
    STDMETHOD(GetOverlayInfo)(LPWSTR pwszIconFile, int cchMax, int *pIndex, DWORD* pdwFlags);
    STDMETHOD(GetPriority)(int* pPriority);
    STDMETHOD(IsMemberOf)(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib);

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_ICON)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CIcon)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IIcon)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IShellIconOverlayIdentifier)
END_COM_MAP()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }

protected:

};
```

**Icon.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Icon.h"
#using <system.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

STDMETHODIMP CIcon::GetOverlayInfo(LPWSTR pwszIconFile, int cchMax, int * pIndex, DWORD * pdwFlags)
{
    GetModuleFileNameW(_AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance(), pwszIconFile, cchMax);
    *pIndex = 0;
    *pdwFlags = ISIOI_ICONFILE | ISIOI_ICONINDEX;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CIcon::GetPriority(int * pPriority)
{    
    *pPriority = 0;
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CIcon::IsMemberOf(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib)
{       
    wchar_t *s = _wcsdup(pwszPath);
    HRESULT r = S_FALSE;
    _wcslwr_s(s, 1);
    r = S_OK;
    free(s);
    return r;
}

CIcon::CIcon() {
}
```

**ExplorerSync.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ExplorerSync_i.h"
#include "dllmain.h"
#include "Icon.h"
#using <system.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace ATL;

STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
{
            return _AtlModule.DllCanUnloadNow();
    }

_Check_return_
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(_In_ REFCLSID rclsid, _In_ REFIID riid, _Outptr_ LPVOID* ppv)
{
        return _AtlModule.DllGetClassObject(rclsid, riid, ppv);
}

STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{   
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllRegisterServer();

    // not possible to instantiate, because it is abstract according to error message
    //CIcon *cIcon = new (std::nothrow) CIcon();

        return hr;
}

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllUnregisterServer();
        return hr;
}

STDAPI DllInstall(BOOL bInstall, _In_opt_  LPCWSTR pszCmdLine)
{   
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    static const wchar_t szUserSwitch[] = L"user";

    if (pszCmdLine != NULL)
    {
        if (_wcsnicmp(pszCmdLine, szUserSwitch, _countof(szUserSwitch)) == 0)
        {
            ATL::AtlSetPerUserRegistration(true);
        }
    }

    if (bInstall)
    {   
        hr = DllRegisterServer();
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            DllUnregisterServer();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = DllUnregisterServer();
    }

    return hr;
}
```

So I used primarily the code from the example mentioned above and because it did not work, I changed the code a bit according to my thoughts.

The problem is not the compiling. This works and registration via regsvr32 as well without any errors. But with some event log entries I found out, that DllRegisterServer is the only method which is called. All the other functions (especially the interface implementations for the icons) are not called at all. Although it's not done in the example, I tried to instantiate the Icon class in the DllRegisterServer method in the hope it helps, but I cannot do that (error message: Icon is abstract and cannot be instantiated).

So can anybody tell me, what's going wrong, please?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you checked (with RegEdit) to make sure that your overlay is registered with Explorer under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows 
   \CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`?  It is unusual to see ATL and CLR used together (not a criticism, just commenting).

Comment: Yes, I did. When I use the code from the example in the rgs file, the registry entries are set. However, I don't know exactly if I have to consider something special with the CLSIDs? Do I have to replace the CLSID from the example by my own? And if yes where do I get it? For now, I only replaced the class names. CLR I have used for the event logger, but for a better clarity, I have removed this code since it shouldn't influence the functionality of the icons.

Comment: You should use your own CLSID.  Your project should have generated its own rgs file which resembles the top part of the one from the example, but contains your own CLSID.  The bottom part of the example, in bold, is what was added to support Explorer.  And the CLSID placed there is just copied from the one that was already present, from the top of the rgs file.

Comment: A rgs file was automatically created but was empty, so I copied the complete content from the webpage. But since the file was empty, there wasn't any CLSID for my project in there.

Comment: Initially, using VS 2015, I created an ATL project without changing the wizard's default settings, and it generated a properly populated rgs file, so I figured you must have done something wrong (or you were only looking at the empty MyOverlayIconPS rgs).  But then, I tried the same thing with VS 2013, and it gave me the empty rgs file!  Then I found that VS 2013 would populate the rgs file if I checked "Support COM+ 1.0" and "Support Component Registrar" in the ATL project wizard.

Comment: I now used again some time to try setting up a new project and, as you said, I really have a rgs file for the created class which has content as in the example. But when I add the content from the example website, the entry in the registry is not set anymore. This worked only in the other rgs file (for the class generated by default I guess). So one idea I have is, that I need to create an instance for my new class in the DllRegisterServer method (since this is the only method which is currently executed). However in the example they do not do anything like that. Or do you have another idea?